# PHP User Session not persisting between tabs

Tags: php, session, user-accounts

I have come across an issue I have never seen before.  I am storing logged in user session information in a `$_SESSION['user']` variable (just like I do on all my other sites.) But when I open the site in another tab, in the same Chrome browser window, the session does not persist in that tab. I am logged out in one tab, and logged in in another tab. This is bewildering to me since I was sure user sessions were browser-level, not tab level. This is a normal clean installation of Chrome with no extensions.

I can navigate around on the logged-in tab just fine, do hard refresh and clear the cache, all that good stuff, and still remain logged in. But in the tab right next to it, I can refresh as many times as I want and navigate to all kinds of pages, and still remain logged out. I can hop between the two tabs and navigate them both simultaneously—still the issue persists.

I have `session_start()` at the beginning of every page. I am even echoing the user session in the footer of the site and sure enough, it is fully populating in one tab and completely absent from the other.

**EDIT:** To confirm, I created a simple test.php on my domain containing exactly this code: `<?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['user']['uid']; ?>`.  I fully logged out of my session. I opened my site in two separate tabs. I logged into one tab. I then added /test.php to my URL in both tabs. In the first tab, I got a blank page. In the second, I got 1 (my user ID). The blank tab stayed blank even after multiple hard refreshes, and the "1" page stayed "1" even after multiple hard refreshes. How can I prevent this behavior? It is likely users will want to use multiple tabs to navigate and this behavior is preventing that.

Can someone think of any reason this could be happening?

Comment: unable to confirm that - appears fine so there would appear to be something in your code. My guess is somewhere there is some code that destroys the session.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius The only code I know of that could accomplish that is `session_destroy()`, and I do not have that on any page.  Also, if the session was destroyed in one tab, wouldn't that also log me out of the other tab as well, since the session is browser-level?

Comment: Have you done a very simple test - two new pages with `session_start` code and logic to test the session exists ? Do not include any other files

Comment: Are you doing anything with local storage, too?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius That is a very good idea. I created a simple page called test.php on my domain with this content: `<?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['user']['uid']; ?>` When I load it on the first tab I get a blank page, when I load it on the second tab I get 1 (my UID). When I open a new tab I also get 1. I am bewildered.

Comment: @ChrisHaas No, I am not.

Comment: I just added information about my new test to my post. I also happened to open it in yet another new tab and I am not logged in in that one, while being logged in in two other tabs. All in the same window.

Comment: Forgive me if I misunderstood but you have created a single new script and used the original login and code as a test? I suggested creating 2 new pages - in one set a simple session vairable that uyou can test in the other without ANY references to your current code that is having issues

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Okay, that seems to work.  So I assume the issue must be somewhere in my code... but I didn't even think it was physically possible for any code to do what this code is doing, a.k.a. making session variables that do not persist from page to page.  It's not complicated, I just query my user table for a matching email & password and then populate `$_SESSION['user']` with the resulting `$result->fetch_assoc()`.  This issue also means I have to log in all the time, even though I specifically set my session gc max lifespan to 7200 (2h) I still have to relogin all the time.

Comment: I gues that somewhere in your code you do have something squirrelled away that is killing the session variables

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius But again, if the session variables were being killed, wouldn't that kill the session on every tab?  I can navigate around from page to page in both a logged-out and logged-in tab simultaneously, I don't get logged out from both tabs.

Answer (score -1):

Getting this same issue at the moment....its really frustrating. One chrome tab shows a different phpsessid and what makes it worst is that it is the same url and its persistent when refreshing both tabs. This means that the sessions are not being destroyed and recreated. Its really peculiar.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32161157)